# How can I find out If a disk partition is safe to delete?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, windows-11

Windows 11

I'm just looking through Disk Management and noticed there's a 93GB "Primary Partition" with 100% free space. How can I find out what that partition is used for?

I thought a "Primary Partition" was related to how the system boots, but the C: partition already has "Boot" in its Status ("Boot, Page File, Crash Dump, Basic Data Partition").

Does this setup look OK/typical?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> How can I find out what that partition is used for?

When the partition is not a special one (containing boot or recovery, etc) and has an NTFS or FAT32 filesystem on it, you can simply right-click the partition and assign a driveletter to it. You will then get it visible in Explorer and you can navigate it.

Disk manager however tells you, that the partition you ask about does not have an NTFS partition. It is a large partition. Because it is not a windows native partition, disk manager doesn't know what it is. It says its 100% free, but I would not be surprised, if the partition is a Linux parition and may even contain data.

To be absolutely sure, use a linux boot disk and examine it in there.